# Issue with absolute positioned element that to be shown inside a scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, absolute

We are using a dropdown plugin, which is hiding original dropdown and painting an input text element below the original element. And the options are being painted from an unordered list(which are appended to body)  with position as absolute.

This is working fine. But when the select/input element is painted inside an internal scrollable div and when we scroll the internal div, the position of list is not getting changed(It is not sticking to text box). But, when we scroll with external scrollbar, position of  list is moving as expected(sticking to text box).

Please provide your inputs to solve this.

PFA sample HTML at 
https://plnkr.co/edit/PsVIOrVeMILsfSBUAlfW?p=preview

```css
#scrollable {
  max-height:200px;
  overflow:scroll;
}

input{ 
  width:200px;
}

ul {
  background:lightgrey;
  border:1px solid black;
  width:160px;
  position:absolute;
  top:13px;
   left:185px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable">

    This is scrollable conatiner 
    <input type="text" name="textbox"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Sed est mauris,<br>ut massa eget ligula vestibulum sodales. In lacinia scelerisque mollis. Nulla semper quam quis justo hendrerit, at faucibus turpis lobortis. Ut enim est, por.</p>

</div>
<ul><li>First</li><li>Second</li><li>Third</li></ul>
```

Comment: The `<ul>` is supposed to extend outside the scrolling div, correct?

Comment: center tag has been deprecated - I would use a div and then just make that position relative - https://plnkr.co/edit/ahJ7gOWe8vnS1XjBIjIW?p=preview

Comment: Toby - Yes, Corrected the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add *position:relative* on the container

```
  #scrollable{
            position:relative;
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
    body{
      max-height:300px;
      overflow:scroll;
    }
      #scrollable{
        max-height:200px;
        overflow:scroll;
        position:relative;
      }
      input{
        width:200px;
      }
      ul{
        background:lightgrey;
        border:1px solid black;
        width:160px;
        position:absolute;
        top:5px;
        left:245px;
      }
      li{
        list-style-type:none;
        text-align:left;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="scrollable">
      <center>
      This is scrollable conatiner 
      <input type="text" name="textbox"/>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Sed est mauris,<br> vestibulum ut diam aliquet, volutpat pellentesque o
      rci. Quisque consequat posuere est, vel commodo mi consequat consequat. Cras bibendum eros in dolor finibus egestas. Morbi tempor odio dignissim, pellentesque odio ut, vestibulum nulla. Sed ut massa eget ligula vestibulum sodales. In lacinia scelerisque mollis. Nulla semper quam quis justo hendrerit, at faucibus turpis lobortis. Ut enim est, porttitor at nunc ac, consectetur fringilla lacus. Nunc euismod sapien et ligula condimentum, eu pharetra velit molestie.</p>
      <ul><li>First</li><li>Second</li><li>Third</li></ul>
      </center>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Sed est mauris, vestibulum ut diam aliquet, volutpat pellentesque o
      rci. Quisque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Sed est mauris, vestibulum ut diam aliquet, volutpat pellentesque o
      rci. Quisque consequat posuere est, vel cLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Sed est mauris, vestibulum ut diam aliquet, volutpat pellentesque o
      rci. Quisque consequat posuere est, vel commodo mi consequat consequat. Cras bibendum eros in dolor finibus egestas. Morbi tempor odio dignissim, pellentesque odio ut, vestibulum nulla. Sed ut massa eget ligula vestibulum sodales. In lacinia scelerisque mollis. Nulla semper quam quis justo hendrerit, at faucibus turpis lobortis. Ut enim est, porttitor at nunc ac, consectetur fringilla lacus. Nunc euismod sapien et ligula condimentum, eu pharetra velit molestie.</p>
      ommodo mi consequat consequat. Cras bibendum eros in dolor finibus egestas. Morbi tempor odio dignissim, pellentesque odio ut, vestibulum nulla. Sed ut massa eget ligula vestibulum sodales. In lacinia scelerisque mollis. Nulla semper quam quis justo hendrerit, at faucibus turpis lobortis. Ut enim est, porttitor at nunc ac, consectetur fringilla lacus. Nunc euismod sapien et ligula condimentum, eu pharetra velit molestie.</p>
       consequat posuere est, vel commodo mi consequat consequat. Cras bibendum eros in dolor finibus egestas. Morbi tempor odio dignissim, pellentesque odio ut, vestibulum nulla. Sed ut massa eget ligula vestibulum sodales. In lacinia scelerisque mollis. Nulla semper quam quis justo hendrerit, at faucibus turpis lobortis. Ut enim est, porttitor at nunc ac, consectetur fringilla lacus. Nunc euismod sapien et ligula condimentum, eu pharetra velit molestie.</p>
      </p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: lonut : Thank you for the response. I have added the markup incorrectly. ul tag will come outside the scrollable div. Could you please suggest a solution for that. Updated the question and plnkr.

Comment: you can't do this from CSS you have to use a JS solution , and on scrolling   recalculate the list position